How to test and assert my chess engine's Elo using Stockfish?
I have developed a chess engine in C# and I want to estimate its Elo rating by playing it against Stockfish, a well-known and highly-rated chess engine. My goal is to set up matches between my engine and Stockfish, collect the results, and then calculate the estimated Elo rating of my engine.
My chess engine is written in C# and follows the UCI protocol for communication.
I have downloaded the Stockfish program. How should I set up and manage the matches between my engine and Stockfish to give the estimation on my engine's elo?

FYI there is an excellent Chess site also owned by Prosus - indeed there are many programmers on it as well as Chess champs.  https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32913/how-should-i-configure-stockfish-if-i-want-it-to-play-as-a-2800-elo-player-witho for example

I am not sure what is being asked here. If your engine uses a well-known protocol and your test engine follows the same protocol, then you can set up mid-way games to see if your engine takes classical strategies that you expect (either in one move or N moves). As you add more scenarios you can become more confident in your engine's ability.

Could you amplify what bit you are stuck on? Is it the protocol itself, or setting up mid-way games, or...?
